# Error in getting Google Maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services

I am Developing an Andorid Applicaiton which require Google Maps to The application.

For That I am Using the same Example in Following Link.

[**Link For Google Maps.**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

### in That I had Applied API KEY to andorid Manifist file.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="API KEY" />
```

### And I am Getting Following Errors.

```
         FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My XML File is:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

### My Andorid Manifest File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My App Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I had added **google-play-services_lib** also to my project.

Please help me where I am getting the error? and what should I do to solve this errors.

And also tell me in above application where should I change.

Thank you.

Comment: post your xml file code

Comment: @Nirav in which version you are trying to run this app?

Comment: post AndroidManifest.xml and layout file

Comment: @PareshMayani My version is     android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"

Comment: my god...I am asking about android version :)

Comment: I think you have to add  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> the following line in your manifest.

Comment: @NiravDabhi not manifest version. its sdk version

Comment: Check this error first, you missed something in your xml file: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: post your java code also

Comment: @PareshMayani Android version is 4.2

Comment: @Lokesh See my edited question for Menifest file and XML file

Comment: @NiravDabhi you are missing `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in manifest file and you have this   `<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />` twice

Comment: Check with changing this line in your xml.... android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: @Nil Still its not working

Comment: have you check with @Raghunandan comment or my previous comment.

Comment: Ya @Nil.. I had checked your comment and Now i am checking according to Raghunandan 's comment

Comment: solve the problem or not???

Comment: Hey I had checked @Raghunandan's answer but it cant generate maps

Comment: @NiravDabhi the problem isn't maps not being displayed. its about missing a metag in application manifest. re-read the stacktrace. FOr further problem re-run and re-post the stacktrace

Comment: @NiravDabhi testing on a real device or emulator??

Comment: Please see my updated logcat

Comment: @NiravDabhi Do you test it on a real device??

Comment: Yes I test on both. Emulater and Android 4.2 Device both

Comment: @NiravDabhi post your MainActivity also

Comment: Finally I got it. Thanks alot

Comment: What you change plz mentioned so everyone will get that..

Comment: Just changed my Menifest file as Simple Plan suggested. @Nil..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logcat clearly said

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected
>   4323000 but found 0. You must have the following declaration within
>   the element:

Try to add Google play services version using `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml` file like

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Make your `manifest.xml` like

```
....<application>
 ..............
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Key" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: Hey is that error because of API key that I had passed to the Android

Comment: @NiravDabhi no error becoz you need to add google play services version in your `manifest.xml`.it's becoz latest google play services required to add version into your `manifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 4):

### Issue:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected
>   4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within
>   the  element:

### Solution:

Include Google play services version inside your manifest file.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You can read about [referencing Google play services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

Comment: @NiravDabhi please read the above answer perfectly and please refer document link given to know more about this issue.

Comment: @NiravDabhi what do you see on the screen after update no maps but do you see zoom in/out buttons?

Comment: @NiravDabhi I have already checked your updated log and issue is still the same.

Comment: @PareshMayani Hey thanks for your help I also upvoted your question. But I tried the code of Simple Plan first and it worked. But thanks alot dude