# Getting Error in Display Google Maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication, error-handling

I am developing an google Map application

### For My Code Please See Following Link.

**[Link For Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012053/error-in-getting-google-maps-in-android)**

I had run that application completely and that was worked.
But I **changed Package and Changed API key which I had mentioned in menifest File.**

### For that:

- I had reffered Lots of link for that and also **clean the project.**
- **Uninstall the application from deveice with its data completely** and **again run with different key.**

But result is same.

### In that I got Following Errors:

```
Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.rchat, API Key: AIzaSyCvFmp6pNM6LHn4AEuWvztuePsIQNLPtZo, Certificate Fingerprint: E2C6F24150FD2483E06F709DF128962CEF35A63E

Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

please help me for that. The **mapview is displaying with white background but map doesnt displaying.**

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you generated new API key from developer console?

Comment: Ofcorse I had. And lots of time I had changed key with certificates with different application package.

Comment: ok fine now tell me did you test this app in Emulator?

Comment: No I had test application in my tablet device.

Comment: And also cross check you change package name in your manifest.xml file?

Comment: yaaa dear I also checked that properly

Comment: then your issue is very strange. can you post your manifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Include the following code to your manifest file.

```
 <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something may wrong in your Manifest.xml. After changing the package name, did you change permission package name?

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.rchat.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.rchat.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build
        copy SHA1 fingerprint:

Step 2: register google account and go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/
        click on "Create New Android key"
        paste your sha1 and package name your's project

Step 3: 
      
    .permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

```
<uses-permission android:name="<your_package_name>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 

<application

    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<your_api_key>" />


</application>
```

Note: delete old app on android device , and run again. hope this help for you.